# type 'String' does not conform to protocol 'NilLiteralConvertiblle'

Tags: ios, ios7, swift

this line of Code:

```
var errorView = UIAlertView(title: errorTitle, message: errorString, delegate:self, cancelButtonTitle: "Cancel", otherButtonTitles: "OK", nil)
```

rewritten from Objective-C Code:

```
 UIAlertView *errorView =
        [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:errorTitle
            message:errorString delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil
            otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
```

which gives me this error:

> type 'String' does not conform to protocol 'NilLiteralConvertiblle'

I can fix it by not putting nil in the end, but I just don't know why, does somebody know the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [Variadic Parameter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-XID_243) which required `nil` termination in Objective-C, but doesn't in Swift.

Swift method signature:

```
init(title: String, message: String, delegate: UIAlertViewDelegate?, cancelButtonTitle: String?, otherButtonTitles firstButtonTitle: String, _ moreButtonTitles: String...)
```

Objective-C method signatire:

```
- (instancetype)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title message:(NSString *)message delegate:(id /*<UIAlertViewDelegate>*/)delegate cancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)cancelButtonTitle otherButtonTitles:(NSString *)otherButtonTitles, ... NS_REQUIRES_NIL_TERMINATION
```

*Technically, it's the `moreButtonTitles` that is the variadic parameter in Swift.*